Is there any way to tell who set a SQL Server database to ReadOnly?
One of the databases on a SQL Server 2017 instance is set to ReadOnly. Is there any way to find out what user account may have set that specific DB to ReadOnly?
I do not know of any automatic means that would put a SQL DB in ReadOnly mode (Recovery?), but that would also answer the question of who made the DB read-only.

Not sure if it's logged somewhere, perhaps you can peruse the default trace? select top 300 tt.*  from sys.traces t  cross apply sys.fn_trace_gettable(path, null) tt  left join sys.trace_events tr  ON tr.trace_event_id = tt.EventClass where EventClass = 164 and DatabaseName = '<yourdb>'  order by StartTime desc

Might want to add and objectType = 16964 for database. You can see the error log for when this change was done to better correlate the events

Thanks @siggemannen, but I can only get results back from that query if I omit the database name and object type from the WHERE clause
